# How to use .so file in c code android

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface

I have a .so file which I want to load and use functions in it for my android application. Normally, to use it with Java code I can use `System.loadLibrary()` `or System.load()`

However, I dont load it with Java code, I only want to load it with C code to call functions inside. But I dont know the right way to do it.
Especially, the .so file is not included in apk file. I want to use C code in apk and load the .so file locating on SDCARD

Comment: Read about [`dlopen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and related functions.

Comment: Could you give me a example? I easily understand the problem by example

Comment: Did you actually read the linked manual page? Did you look at the example at the bottom? Now when you know what functions to use, have you tried searching for other examples?

Comment: Yeah. Your reference for me is really good. Thats is what I'm looking for. I'm sorry for asking before read it carefully. Now I can understand. Btw, I want ask you one more thing. The .so file was built by ndk-build. Is it possible to work perfect with dlopen and  dlsym? Because I'm new to this so I just ask to make sure before going deeper

Answer (score 0):

[dlopen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlopen.html) to load the library, followed by [dlsym()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dlsym.html) to obtain the address associated with a symbol defined in the library.

```
void* my_library = dlopen("libMine.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if (my_library == NULL) 
{
   // report error ...
} 
else 
{
   // use the result in a call to dlsym
}
```